# With ARC, how to correctly set a property with side effect?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class that uses automatic reference counting. Within the class, I have a property as described below. When I set the reminder for the class, I want the side effect of changing the button title to take place.

Here's my code:

in the .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)Reminder* reminder;
```

in the .m file:
    @synthesize reminder;

```
  -(void)setReminder:(Reminder *)reminder_
    {
//what else do I need to do here?
        reminder = reminder_;
         if(!reminder.useSound.boolValue)
        {
             onOffButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Off", @"Off title");

        }else
        {
            onOffButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"On", @"On title");
        }
    }
```

I know that without ARC I would do something like this:

```
-(void)setReminder:(Reminder *)reminder_

{

[reminder release];
reminder = [reminder_ retain];


     if(!reminder.useSound.boolValue)
    {
         onOffButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Off", @"Off title");

    }else
    {
        onOffButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"On", @"On title");
    }
}
```

**Do I need to do anything else within my ARC enabled setter method to ensure that the strong variable is retained properly?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to write your own setter for side effects like this. Use [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)!

Make the controller that owns the button observe this object's `reminder` property:

```
[reminderOwner addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"reminder"
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                   context:NULL];
```

The [`options` argument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-SW2) specifies what information about the state of the observed object you'd like passed along when the observation is made.

Then your controller will be apprised whenever this property changes value (note that this will only occur if the property is set in a "Key-Value compliant" manner, the handiest way being via the setter method* -- changing the ivar directly doesn't count).

You need to implement [`observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-BBCBDGCJ) in your controller:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // Distinguish between observations if necessary; you can also
    // use the |object| argument for this.
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"reminder"] ){
        // Update button text with contents of |change| dictionary
        Reminder * reminder = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        if(!reminder.useSound.boolValue)
        {
             onOffButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Off", @"Off title");

        }else
        {
            onOffButton.title = NSLocalizedString(@"On", @"On title");
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and to, uh, answer your actual question, I believe that your memory management is fine. `reminder` is synthesized to be a `__strong`-qualified variable, which means ARC will retain whatever you put there.

---

*Which is why you've heard not to use setters in `init` and `dealloc`.

Comment: But is it possible without KVO and via overriding?

Comment: sorry wrong wording at 5:07AM coding. Is there a way to implement a setter yourself and still have ARC do your memory management?

Comment: Oh, I see. Sure there is; AFAIK the setter that Alex Stone has presented in his first snippet is completely ARC-correct. (I added a sentence at the end of my answer to indicate this.)

Comment: Thanks. In that case wouldn't it be cleaner to just implement a setter? I mean if you have significant stuff going on in there you're gonna differentiate the strings anyway into different methods, and implementing doing it Alex's way you don't have to remove observers and such. It's also less code to maintain that way, without the ugly observer adding/removing code in your eyes.

Comment: It's a judgement call; it could certainly be that for Alex's case, it makes more sense to put the button-updating directly into the setter. I think that generally one should try to avoid putting that kind of activity into a setter method, however, and KVO is such a nice facility for that.

Comment: Thanks for the great piece of code! There are some places where I've used even uglier code when KVO would've been a better answer. I will start using KVO in such cases. I've tested the setter's side effect as presented in the first snipped, and the onOffButton is nil before viewDidLoad gets called. I moved the code to set the initial value of the button into viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Alex: You can register for observations whenever you like (i.e., in `viewDidLoad`), and you can get an observation immediately by specifying [`NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial). Glad it was helpful.